# Implicit conversion operator priority

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, standards, overload-resolution

In the following piece of code ([live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3929a88c63138ec)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    struct S {
        operator bool        () const { return false; }
        operator std::string () const { return "false"; }
    } s;
    std::cout << s << "\n"; // outputs 0
}
```

How does the compiler *choose* to pick the implicit conversion to `bool` over `std::string`?

My hypothesis is that in this case, it might be purely the order of declaration of the different flavours of [`std::basic_ostream::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), but is it all? Does the standard say something about picking a specific implicit conversion?

Comment: Just to nitpick, nothing is ever implicitly cast. Types are implicitly converted, but a *cast* means *explicit conversion*.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, it's good to know the specific terminology. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that `std::string` is not a standalone type, it's really a class template specialization - `std::basic_string<char>`. The very important detail is that the potential overload for streaming a `std::string` does not take a `std::string const&` argument, it is a [function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) that deduces a `std::basic_string const&`:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Template deduction *never considers conversions*. Name lookup will find this function template, and then discard at as being non-viable due to deduction failure. `S` is not a `basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>` for any such types, so we're done. The only viable stream operators would be all the integral ones, of which `bool` is the best match.

If there specifically was a function with signature:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::string const& );
```

Then the call would be ambiguous - you'd get two user-defined conversions that would be equivalently ranked.

---

This is easy to verify by using our own functions instead of the million overloads for `operator<<`:

```
void foo(bool ); // #1
void foo(std::string ); // #2

void bar(bool );  // #3
template <class C, class T, class A>
void bar(std::basic_string<C,T,A> ); // #4

foo(S{}); // error: ambiguous
bar(S{}); // calls #3
```

Comment: @YSC : I have edited mine to correct it.  I hadn't realized at the time it is now an imperfect version of Barry's.  I've still left it, because I think the "don't do that, then" advice is useful.

Comment: @Barry, deduction succeeds for template operator <<. The compiler choose the member function because it is not a template. See my answer.

Comment: A clear way to see this for OP is to comment out `operator bool` from the original code... then it fails to compile (it doesn't call the string convertor)

Answer (score 3):

```
ostream& operator<<( bool value );
```

Is a member function of `std::ostream`.  On the other hand:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::string& str);
```

Is a standalone function - *which is actually declared as a template*.  A reference to `S` doesn't match any of the templates - so it isn't considered for template expansion.

---

It is possible to uniquely determine which overload should be selected, but I suggest you don't do that.

a) This is always one of the tricky corners of the standard (so you may encounter compiler bugs;

b) future developers will always find the code hard to read.

My suggestion is to avoid the problem entirely by just making your conversion operators explicit,  or give them names like `to_bool()` and `to_string()`.

Comment: Member/nonmember is irrelevant. It's the templateness that's the problem.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion (prefer explicit conversions), but I'm not that sure about your explanation. See [this example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/174a94a1e2fdcb7e).

Comment: @T.C. Ah-ha!  Thanks.