# Implicit conversion and user defined conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

When I write code like this:

```cpp
struct foo {
    operator int() const { return 1; }
};
int main() {
    foo a, b;
    auto tmp = (a < b);
}
```

it works, but while I write code like this:

```cpp
struct foo {
    operator string() const { return string("foo"); }
};
int main() {
    foo a, b;
    auto tmp = (a < b);
}
```

Compiler(clang++) says that `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('foo' and 'foo')`

I wonder why, as both `string` type and `int` type have comparison operators, but when `foo` has a user defined `int` conversion, it will implicit convert to `int` to compare, however when `foo` only has a user defined `string` conversion, compiler doesn't do implicit conversion though `(string)a<(string)b` works well.

Comment: I dont know the rule that causes this, but most likely it has something to do with `int` being a built in type

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252023/implicit-conversion-operator-priority

Comment: @NathanOliver imho question isnt really a dupe, but the answer pefectly explains also this one

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah,  that is why I did not close it myself.  Not sure if it should be closed as a dupe or not but the answer does explain the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit conversion operator priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252023/implicit-conversion-operator-priority)

Comment: @Tsumiki I think this one deserves its own answer, I would expect [this](http://ideone.com/TAQlJJ) to compile, or maybe I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that string is not a basic type. `std::string` is a specialization of a template, specifically `std::basic_string<char>`

So `operator <` is defined as

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
    bool operator< (const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> &_Left,  const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> &_Right);
```

It will work with:

```
auto tmp = (static_cast<std::string>(a) < static_cast<std::string>(b));
```

Then `operator <` becomes:

```
bool std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(const std::string &_Left, const std::string &_Right)
```

Comment: And because user defined conversion are not considered for template function specialization. See this related answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252023/implicit-conversion-operator-priority/42253006#42253006].